# Sketch: Resize Element and Keep Content Centered

Tags: resize, alignment, sketch-app

Is it possible to resize a grouped element, and preserve the centering of its child elements? Also, is it possible when resizing the group element that the elements inside the group, preserve their ratio?

It's getting a bit tiresome having to realign the children elements every time I resize the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach.
For instance we have several shapes:
[image]

Select all the shapes and group them <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. Select the group and lock its size by pressing lock icon in inspector view.
[image]

After you can resize the group and all child shapes will preserve their ratio and position:
[image]